# Decentralising the presentation tier/layer of a DApp

Tags: dapp-development, dapps

Though the data/state tier (i.e., the ledger), business logic tier (i.e., smart contracts) and storage tier (i.e., file storage e.g., IPFS, etc) is decentralised, understand that the presentation layer of DApps is still centralized on a web server, which somewhat goes against the spirit of a truly decentralized application.

How then can one build a truly decentralized for all 4 tiers?

Nathan Aw

Answer (score 1):

This is wat [Swarm](https://github.com/ethersphere/swarm) is for. You could also host your web page on IPFS, though.

Mist can open Swarm Dapps using the `bzz` protocol, which is a whole lot different from `http`. There's also a gateway which enables dapps to be used by other browsers, but of course, that gateway is centralized.

Check out the [Swarm Dapp](http://swarm-gateways.net/bzz:/theswarm.eth/)

Comment: thanks bro -- how then one run the web page? there should be an IP address with ports, etc

Comment: `bzz` is not accessible to normal browsers - only specialized browser like Mist. No `http`needed, or IP addresses, or ports.